# Accessing my Class and presenting the output on the presentation layer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, arraylist, datareader

I have a class that I have written to run a stored procedure, start a datareader and put the contents into a arraylist.

### CLASS CODE

```
public class GHPSlider
{
    private clsDbAccess _db;
    private clsDbAccess _tmpDb;

    public ArrayList getBanners(int thisBannerType)
    {
        ArrayList HeroBanners = new ArrayList();
        SqlDataReader _dr = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = _db.Command;
        if (_db.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            _db.Connection.Open();
        }
        cmd = _db.Command;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "GetGHPSlides";
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", thisBannerType);
        _dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        if (_dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (_dr.Read())
            {
                object[] values = new object[_dr.FieldCount];
                _dr.GetValues(values);
                HeroBanners.Add(values);
            }
        }
        _dr.Close();

        return HeroBanners;
    }
}
```

On my code-behind I am trying to access the ArrayList so that I can loop through it and output the code to the presentation layer. I am fairly new to the n-tier way of programming and could use some help to get me in the right direction.

### CODE-BEHIND CODE

```
Public Function GetHeros() As String

    Dim thisTestSubject As ArrayList = New GHPSlider.getBanners(1)
    'Loop through thisTestSubject ArrayList and place into HTML string to pass to literal or label
    thisBannerSlideBuilderHTML = "<div style='z-index:0;background-color:#FFF;'><a href='" + thisBannerSlideURL.ToString() + "' onclick='RecordBannerClick(this, 'Hero', 'GHP', '" + thisBannerSlideTitle.ToString() + "');'><img alt='" + thisBannerSlideTitle.ToString() + "' src='" + thisBannerSlideImagePath.ToString() + "' /></a></div>";
    'Place Inside Literal or Label to display to presentation layer

End Function
```

If someone could help point me in the right direction, it would be wonderful! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having some trouble thinking about the question, I guess.  What's the exact issue, here?  Are you unable to access your array from the other class?

Comment: I am unable to figure out how to:  1) Access my arraylist properly that resides in the class and 2) How to loop through said ArrayList to build the HTML that will be passed into the presentation layer.

Comment: Is your code not working?  It's a little strange that you're manually crafting HTML in a .NET application (I'm assuming ASP.NET), but not unheard of.  But that has nothing to do with accessing the class.  What's not working?

Comment: If this is ASP.NET you should start learning that ;) Use controls instead of concatenating a html string. Btw, why do you use C# and VB.NET?

Comment: If you're unable to access the class that you have, you're going to need to instantiate it.  For instance, `GHPSlider slider = new GHPSlider();`

From there, you'll be able to access properties and methods with `slider.getBanners();`

Comment: This is an n-tier solution that is 8-10 years old code with multiple developers over the time. It is a mix of vb/c# and is very inefficient.  However, the powers that be have scrapped upgrading to MVC and moving to the next level. Instead, they cut resources and developers and want us to just keep working on this platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're unable to access the class that you have, you're going to need to instantiate it. For instance,

```
GHPSlider slider = new GHPSlider();
```

From there, you'll be able to access properties and methods with

```
slider.getBanners();
```

The code you are currently using is pretty cryptic, I'm not sure what you're using it for, so it may be viable.  However, you may want to read a bit about layering programs, it'll help you mentally organize this stuff a bit.  I know you don't really have a Data Layer, but reading about Data Access Layers will probably help you to understand the architecture behind it.

---

I can only really provide help from the C# standpoint, but you may be able to port it over.

For iterating through the values of an array, it really depends on the purpose.  In simplistic coding, let's say you had an array of ten values.  Iterating through them with a `for` loop will let you get each value, by passing it to another command.

```
int[] array = new int[p];

        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        {
            array[i] = i;
            Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
        }
```

The output of this is a count from 0-9.

[Help with arrays!](http://www.dotnetperls.com/array)

Now, more specifically, [ArrayList](http://www.dotnetperls.com/arraylist)

I understand you are using older code, hence, `ArrayList`, but the iteration of values with a `for` loop is probably going to be your best bet.

Comment: You got half of my question, might as well give you the credit.

Comment: I could use some help iterating through the columns and rows of my ArrayList so that I can output the strings to the presentation layer via concatenated string to a placeholder or label. Anyone provide any help?

Comment: I'm updating my answer with something that MAY be able to help you.